# Function on the set of limit countable ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-numbers

Let $\Lambda$ be the set of all countable limit ordinals. Does there exist an injective function $f:\Lambda\to\omega_1$ with the properties:

1. $\forall \lambda\in\Lambda:~f(\lambda)<\lambda$
2. $\forall\alpha<\omega_1~~\exists\beta<\omega_1~~\forall\lambda>\beta:~f(\lambda)>\alpha$ ?

Comment: Though the answer below answers your question, you might be interested to know that an injective function $f:\Lambda\to\omega_1$ automatically satisfies $2$: for any $\gamma\leq\alpha$ there is at most one ordinal $a_\gamma$ such that $f(a_\gamma)=\gamma$. Then $\beta=\sup_{\gamma\leq\alpha}a_\gamma$ will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  The first property is known as $f$ being *regressive*.  [Fodor’s Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor%27s_lemma) says that any regressive function on a stationary set is constant on a stationary subset.  In particular, because $\Lambda$ is club (and thus stationary), such $f$ cannot be injective.